# Windows App Cert Failed: System.Net.json

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Trying to upload an App to the Windows 8 Store and running into the following error.

> Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
>   API
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.#ctor(System.String,System.Boolean)
>   in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this
>   application type. System.Net.Json.dll calls this API.

Any ideas on this? I am using a HttpClient that supports the new Async function calls. I made sure I cleaned and rebuilt in "release mode". Either way I'm guessing at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library supports Metro/Store apps, try using it instead of your current approach. And remember to compile all the libraries your app uses in "Any CPU" architecture, so they can be used by ARM devices!

Comment: I actually didn't have anything wrong with the app itself. I just had a stale reference to a JSON lib that I was trying to use and never removed.
BTW. I was able to parse JSON objects using all the System libs on Win8 and did not need an outside library. Thanks.